# Pandas Apply with condition

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-loc

I have customers duplicates with different status because there is a row for each customer subscription/product. I want to generate a `new_status` for the customer and for it to be 'canceled', every subscription status must be 'canceled' together.

I used:

```
df['duplicated'] = df.groupby('customer', as_index=False)['customer'].cumcount()
```

to separate every duplicated in a index to indicate the duplicated values

```
Customer | Status | new_status | duplicated
 X       |canceled|            | 0
 X       |canceled|            | 1
 X       |active  |            | 2
 Y       |canceled|            | 0
 A       |canceled|            | 0
 A       |canceled|            | 1
 B       |active  |            | 0
 B       |canceled|            | 1
```

Thus, I'd like to use .apply and/or .loc to generate:

```
Customer | Status | new_status | duplicated
 X       |canceled|            | 0
 X       |canceled|            | 1
 X       |active  |            | 2
 Y       |canceled|            | 0
 A       |canceled| canceled   | 0
 A       |canceled| canceled   | 1
 B       |active  |            | 0
 B       |canceled|            | 1
```

Comment: Y is not duplicated but it must canceled. the formula can include or not unique values

Comment: Is performance important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you can try doing:

```
df['new_status']=(df.groupby('Customer')['Status'].
  transform(lambda x: x.eq('canceled').all()).map({True:'cancelled'})).fillna(df.new_status)
print(df)

    Customer    Status new_status  duplicated
0   X         canceled             0         
1   X         canceled             1         
2   X         active               2         
3   Y         canceled  cancelled  0         
4   A         canceled  cancelled  0         
5   A         canceled  cancelled  1         
6   B         active               0         
7   B         canceled             1
```

EDIT since expected o/p was changed:

```
df['new_status']=(df.groupby('Customer')['Status'].
             transform(lambda x: x.duplicated(keep=False)&(x.eq('canceled').all()))
                         .map({True:'cancelled',False:''}))
print(df)

  Customer    Status new_status  duplicated
0   X         canceled             0         
1   X         canceled             1         
2   X         active               2         
3   Y         canceled             0         
4   A         canceled  cancelled  0         
5   A         canceled  cancelled  1         
6   B         active               0         
7   B         canceled             1
```

Comment: Call function in `apply` or `transform` should be slow, if large dataframe.

Comment: I think if not necessary.

Comment: 1800 cols. I think it's ok to use .apply and thanks I'm verifying the values, but looks correct

Comment: I edited the post just to be as clear as possible, but the first o/p is even closer to what i want thank you. I'd like to understand more about how did you do that and when to use .map, .eq and .transform

Comment: @RicardoFernandes no problem. So `x.eq('canceled').all()` checks all the grouped items from Status are equal to cancelled or not, so use `all()` returns true. than using map to replace true to 1 and false to blank. best will be try removing some parts of the code and i think you will understand. :) If any prob lemme know. Cheers..!!

Comment: If i just delete the <,False=' ' > in <map({True:'cancelled',False:''})> will it just don't change the supposed false values? (cause it might be filled with other new status)

Comment: not blank, but the way it already is (i didn't show in the example but is filled with some other "new_status"

Comment: @RicardoFernandes edited. check the first part. same concept for second part.

Answer (score 2):

Compare column by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for check if all values are `True`s per groups, then compare `Customer` by [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep=False` for return all dupes. Last chain together by bitwise `AND` (`&`) and set values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m1 = df['Status'].eq('canceled').groupby(df['Customer']).transform('all')
m2 = df['Customer'].duplicated(keep=False)

df['new_status'] = np.where(m1 & m2, 'cancelled', '')
print (df)
  Customer    Status new_status  duplicated
0        X  canceled                      0
1        X  canceled                      1
2        X    active                      2
3        Y  canceled                      0
4        A  canceled  cancelled           0
5        A  canceled  cancelled           1
6        B    active                      0
7        B  canceled                      1
```

Comment: thank you so much. i didn't know the .transform and .eq methods so well